# Why doesn't the add wait for the timeout promise to resolve?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, addition

Trying to play with how promises and async code works by making a calculator that will give me the answer after the given ms.

```
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const add = (number1, number2) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    timeout(1000).then(resolve(number1 + number2));
  });
};

add(5,3).then(result => console.log(result))
```

Why isn't the add function waiting for the timeout? It goes directly to resolve regardless of how many ms I pass in. Omitted reject to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call resolve immediately:

```
const add = (number1, number2) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    timeout(1000).then(() => {
      resolve(number1 + number2);
    });
  });
};
```

As `timeout` is a Promise you can remove your outer completely:

```
const add = (number1, number2) => {
  return timeout(1000).then(() => {
    return number1 + number2;
  });
};
```

Comment: Appreciate it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

`timeout(1000).then(resolve(number1 + number2));`

To:

`timeout(1000).then(() => resolve(number1 + number2))`

Your code is not waiting but just calling resolve.